# router.js Function not executed

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

> ```
> // Filename: router.js
> console.log('TEST ROUTE');
> define([
>     'jquery',
>     'underscore',
>     'backbone',
>     'views/jobs/list'
> ], function($, _, Backbone, JobListView){
>     var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
>         routes: {
>             // Define some URL routes
>             '/dalo/jobs': 'showJobs',
>
>             // Default
>             '*actions': 'defaultAction'
>         }
>     });
>
>     var initialize = function(){
>         var app_router = new AppRouter;
>         app_router.on('route:showJobs', function(){
>             // Call render on the module we loaded in via the dependency array
>             // 'views/jobs/list'
>             console.log('Show Job Route');
>             var jobListView = new JobListView();
>             jobListView.render();
>
>         });
>
>         app_router.on('defaultAction', function(actions){
>             // We have no matching route, lets just log what the URL was
>             console.log('No route:', actions);
>         });
>         Backbone.history.start();
>     };
>     return {
>         initialize: initialize
>     };
> });
> ```

Part of my main.js , i didnt use NEW because it gave issues saying it's not a function not sure if it's related to the error above

```
require(['app'], function(AppView){
    AppView.initialize();
});
```

I did a console.Log after Router.initialize(); at app.js , it can show. I also did a console log all the way above in this app router.js it's also showing, other than that , it doesnt show anything inside the function.

The console is only showing that 2 console Log (After Route.Initialize & Before router.js define

Any advice?
I'm using http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

My App.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router', // Request router.js
], function($, _, Backbone, Router){
    var initialize = function(){
        // Pass in our Router module and call it's initialize function
        Router.initialize();
        console.log('Router Initialized');
    }

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're using a **non-AMD** version of Backbone.js and Underscore.js.

This way you've to add what it's called a "shim" to your main/config file.

> **shim**: Configure the dependencies, exports, and custom initialization for older, traditional "browser globals" scripts that do not use define() to declare the dependencies and set a module value.
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

As you can see this set dependencies and export your lib in order to let you using it in your scripts.

So, in your main/config file, after the paths try adding this shim part:

```
paths: {
    ...
},
shim: {
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    }
}
```

Now I suppose you could proceed ...

Comment: I'm using AMD , for sure checked it already , I will read up on SHIM. What are the difference between dependencies and lib? what about  "text" : "vendor/requirejs-text/text" is that a deps?

Comment: I have already tried adding Shim in it, it still doesn't load anything inside my  app_router.on('route:showJobs', function(){ Thanks for helping :) I cant find any more support :(

Comment: - requirejs/text I suppose it's a plugin to load html file but I suggest you to investigate on it.
- paths is needed for load libraries used in your app, shim are needed if you use non-AMD version of these libraries.

Comment: Could you please add `console.info(Router);` inside the initialize function in the App.js file? So we can see if Router is passed or not. It should return an object with a initialize function

Comment: Hi @ilpaijin , Yes it returns an object with initialize function. Not sure how to read it :x, it does say length is 0. If it does return which is the case it means router is fine? but the console.log inside the app_router.on isnt even showing :\

Comment: So yes, it means that router.initialize is called. Now try to puy a `console.log('Router Initialized');` inside the initalize function in router.js. So you are sure the initialize method is called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41320/discussion-between-user1291223-and-ilpaijin)